# Remove time from date field in Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Following up from my previous question, I need to add on to the formula a way to remove the time from a datetime column.

My current working formula is as follows:

```
=IF(OR(AD9834="In progress",BB9834=""),ROUND($BW$1-AI9834,0),IF(AD9834="Reopened",ROUND(BW1-AP9834,0),ROUND(BW1-AI9834,0)))
```

In the AI column, the datetime looks like this:

```
5/24/2021 1:20:52 PM
```

I basically need to remove the time from the formula.

I tried to do the following:

```
=IF(OR(AD9834="In progress",BB9834=""),ROUND($BW$1-AI9834,1),IF(AD9834="Reopened",ROUND(BW1-AP9834,0),ROUND(BW1-AI9834,1)))
```

But that does not remove the time.

How can I make this work?

Comment: You can use TEXT function to remove the timestamp.

Comment: How can the TEXT function be added to the formula?

Comment: Are they true date or text string?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform mathematical operations with date, you cannot use the `TEXT` function. Use `INT(AI9834)` instead.

```
=IF(OR(AD9834="In progress",BB9834=""),ROUND($BW$1-INT(AI9834),0),IF(AD9834="Reopened",ROUND(BW1-AP9834,0),ROUND(BW1-INT(AI9834),0)))
```

[image]